# Can data persisted using AsyncStorage.setItem() in react-native be acquired from the native code?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

If I store a piece of information using AsyncStorage in react-native, can that value be got from native code in Java for Android and Objective-C on iOS? For example, if I do the following.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

Can this value be gotten from the Java/Objective-C code in a reliable manner?

Comment: Good question, I think it's possible, but not sure how

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, see the document. [asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage)

The only thing you should do is to confirm the path and key.
But we don't do it, instead write code in two platform with same interface

Comment: I've read the documentation, but not seeing any info on how to access the information natively in Java/Objective-C.